# Deform guide force field for particle system

Tags: particles, force-fields, curve-modifier

I have a curve that has a forcefield applied to it to control the path of a particle system.

Is it possible to deform a guide forcefield with a modifier and have the modifier effect the forcefield?

Currently it does deform the original guide but the path of the particles is unaffected.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: maybe it is a better idea to ask how to achieve a certain visual effect than asking for technical details, because someone may come up with a better idea than you thought of. e.g. you could change the curve by hooks.

Answer (score 0):

*Why do you need curve modifier? Curve Guide is as any other curve just with Force Field assigned under Physics. Just deform Curve Guide.*

---

Your issue probably comes from emitter location, that is totally out of guide force range. Also I don't see guide range at all in your screen so you have it set to small.

---

Anyway your proposal works for me ... I just had to enable *Apply on Spline* (first icon in Curve modifier), but since it takes curve just straight to end point ... so I subdivided Curve Guide.

[image]

Here is my file, but if you want to solve issue in your file you should share it. Like now it is full of guessing.

[image]